# Jquery comma separated array in one line to comma separeted array on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have an array inside Jquery(red array) on one line.
I do want it like the blue array seperated on multiple lines.

The red array needs to be like the blue array on the image.

[image]

Can some tell me how to do that, tried a lot of thing.

Comment: This is unclear!

Comment: Looks like your "red array" only contains one single string. To split it check out [String.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var new_array = your_array[0].split(',');//["500,505,506...."]
console.log(new_array);//[500,505,506]
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `split()` somewhere.